# Why am i getting this error when i try to answer my own dns request?

Tags: python, dns, scapy

```
import scapy.all as scapy
p = scapy.DNS(qd=scapy.DNSQR(qname='www.example.com'), an=scapy.DNSRR(rrname='127.0.0.1'))
scapy.send(p)
```

result :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/PROJECTS/server.py", line 3, in <module>
    scapy.send(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 425, in send
    return _send(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 395, in _send
    results = __gen_send(socket, x, inter=inter, loop=loop,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 360, in __gen_send
    s.send(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 605, in send
    self.outs.bind(sdto)
TypeError: AF_PACKET address must be a tuple of two to five elements
```

Why am i getting this error when i try to answer my own dns request ?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happens.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: You haven't specified the address to send to.

Comment: i am sending the requests to myself so the answer should be 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the destination address and the ports.

```
p = scapy.IP(dst='127.0.0.1') / scapy.UDP(sport=53, dport = client_port) / scapy.DNS(qd=scapy.DNSQR(qname='www.example.com'), an=scapy.DNSRR(rrname='127.0.0.1'))
```

Comment: that's right now it is working

Comment: FYI, I've never used scapy. I found this by googling "scapy send dns packet" and there were plenty of examples.

Comment: i did it a couple hours ago it was working fine because i did it when i was thinking i forgot that's why i really thank you bro